# Como fazer um estilo para "imagem quebrada" (quando a imagem não carrega)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como seria possível fazer um estilo CSS para quando a imagem não é carregada na página?

Quando vc tem o link para a imagem, mas por algum motivo ela não é carregada na página, ou se o link ou caminho da imagem estiver errado, ou mesmo se a imagem não estiver na pasta correta ou no servidor, seria possível criar um estilo CSS para tratar essas imagens quebradas?

O normal de se ver é isso quando a imagem não carrega:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mas eu gostaria de algo mais customizado com CSS tipo isso:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa solução não resolve? https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/

Comment: É bem por ai @RicardoPontual se quiser crie um exemplo ai como resposta para ficar registrado no site de forma mais consistente!

Comment: @hugocsl boa iniciativa +1. Dei uma resposta. Acho que o caminho é o JS mesmo.

Comment: Atributo `alt`. Se a imagem não aparecer (se estiver com o endereço errado ou as imagens estiverem desabilitadas) ou se o usuário usar um leitor de tela,a mensagem que ele vai lver é o que estiver no atributo `alt="deu ruim"`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters até curti lá, mas tem como fazer com CSS tb acredito! Não que uma opção seja melhor que a outra...

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo exato é isso mesmo, porém queria tratar esse comportamento padrão para deixar uma mensagem melhor formatada para o usuário

Comment: @hugocsl escrevi uma resposta com o conteúdo do link, com uma explicação básica do funcionamento, para referência caso o link não esteja mais disponível amanhã :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bem, eu não sei se existe alguma forma de resolver isso apenas pelo CSS, mas o que geralmente faço é usar o evento `onerror` para capturar quando há uma falha ao abrir a imagem.

assim:

```
    document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('error', function() {                  
             // sua lógica aqui.
    })
```

É comum definir outro `src` para a imagem, mas você também poderia adicionar uma classe à imagem, ou substituí-la por outro elemento.

Exemplo:

```js
document.querySelector('.error').addEventListener('error', function () {

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.classList.add('img-error');
    div.innerText = 'Imagem falhou';

    this.replaceWith(div)
})
```

```css
.img-error{
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-contents: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF2nj.jpg?s=48&g=1">
<img src="nao_existe" class="error">
```

**Observação**: Se você optar por trocar o `src` da imagem no `onerror`, certifique-se que a imagem fallback usada para "tapar o erro" realmente exista, senão isso causará um loop infinito na chamada de `onerror` (já aconteceu comigo quando esqueci de publicar uma imagem que representava o usuário sem foto).

**Opção 2**

Outra coisa que gosto de fazer é usar `background-image` numa `div` com formatação pré-definida (um `background-color` por exemplo). Assim, quando a imagem falha o carregamento, o `background-color` estará lá pra fazer o fallback.

Comment: Bem massa, valeu pela contribuição!

Answer (score 5):

Baseado na solução *bitsofcode*: https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/

```css
img {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 2;  
  text-align: center;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}
/*
:before pode ser cobrido pela imagem, mas quando a imagem está quebrada ele fica visível
*/
img:before { 
  content: " ";
  display: block;

  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border: 2px dotted rgb(200, 200, 200);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/*
:after mesmo comportamento de :before em relação à imagem
*/
img:after { 
  /* \f127 e a imagem de um link, do FontAwesome
     attr() pega um atributo do elemento, aqui pegando o "alt"
  */
  content: "\f127" " Imagem quebrada: '"  attr(alt) "'";
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<img src="image-que-nao-existe.jgp" alt="alguma imagem" />
```

Adicionei alguns comentários básicos apenas e uma alteração mínima.
No link original em inglês, há uma explicação do uso de `:before` e `:after`, em tradução livre:

> O elemento `<img>` é um elemento substituído. Este é um elemento “cuja
>   aparência e dimensões são definidas por um recurso externo”
>   (Sitepoint). Como o elemento é controlado por uma fonte externa, os
>   pseudo-elementos `:before` e `:after` normalmente não devem funcionar
>   com ele. No entanto, quando a imagem está quebrada e não é carregada,
>   esses pseudo-elementos podem aparecer.

**EDIT** aproveitando a sugestão do @Guilherme, testei nos navegadores:
- Funcionou no Chrome 68, Chrome no Android, Firefox 61 e Opera 36 (meio antigo)
- Não funcionou no IE 9/11, Edge ficou estranho

Comment: Legal Ricardo obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Como comentei no chat para o hugocsl, verifique o suporte para isso, esta é uma característica que em elementos VOID é incomum, atualmente FF e Chrome suportam, mas mobiles, msedge e outras situações não vai conseguir provavelmente ter o mesmo efeito.

Comment: É verdade, eu havia feito uns testes e infelizmente só serve pro FF e Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Usei um CSS qualquer mas você coloque o seu.

**JavaScript puro**

> No evento `onerror` (que é acionado se ocorrer um erro ao carregar a imagem) chame uma função para alterar o conteúdo da `div` que contem a imagem

**Exemplo 1**

```js
function img_erro(){
   var element = document.getElementById("trap_section");
   element.innerHTML = '<div id="trap_top1" style=""></div><div id="section1"><div class="indent"><div><h1>Erro ao carregar imagem</h1><p>Deu ruim</p></div></div></div><div id="trap_bottom1" style=""></div>';
}
```

```css
            .trap_section{
                position: relative;
                width: 500px;
                border: none;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
            #trap_top1{
                position: absolute;
                top: -80px;
                border-top: 80px solid transparent;
                border-right-width: 500px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
            }
            #trap_bottom1{    
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -80px;
                border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
                border-right-width: 500px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
            }
            #section1{
                background: #FF895B;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                height: 200px;
            }
            h1, p{text-align:center;}
```

```html
 
 <div id="trap_section" class="trap_section">
      <img src="sem_url" onerror="img_erro()">
 </div>
```

**Exemplo 2**

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").className = "mystyle";
    document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML = 'Erro ao carregar imagem';
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
<img src="image.gif" onerror="myFunction()">
</div>
```

**Para quem já usa Jquery:**

> Use o evento de erro do jQuery e faça qualquer ação que você deseja se a imagem não puder ser carregada.

- Esconder a tag imagem `$(this).hide();`
- Adicionar conteúdo em seu lugar `$( "#id_div").append(...`

```js
        
$("#img").on("error", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $( "#id_div").append( '<div class="trap_section"><div id="trap_top1" style=""></div><div id="section1"><div class="indent"><div><h1>Erro ao carregar imagem</h1><p>Deu ruim</p></div></div></div><div id="trap_bottom1" style=""></div>');
});
```

```css
    .trap_section{
                    position: relative;
                    width: 500px;
                    border: none;
                    margin-top: 100px;
                }
                #trap_top1{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: -80px;
                    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
                    border-right-width: 500px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
                }
                #trap_bottom1{    
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: -80px;
                    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
                    border-right-width: 500px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(255, 137, 91);
                }
                #section1{
                    background: #FF895B;
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    overflow-y: hidden;
                    height: 200px;
                }
                h1, p{text-align:center;}
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id="id_div">
          <img id="img" src="semUrl">
        </div>
```

**Usando uma imagem padrão**

```html
<!--imagem existente -->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF2nj.jpg?s=48&g=1" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf7KP.png';" />


<!--imagem sem src -->
<img src="semSrc" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf7KP.png';" />
```

Comment: Pra quem já usa jquery no projeto não deixa de ser uma opção

Comment: @hugocsl, editei a resposta e coloquei com javascript puro e com jquery, assim fica à vontade do freguês :)