# Como centralizar em eixo X e Y o texto alternativo da tag img?

Tags: css, html5

Como posso configurar o CSS para deixar o texto alternativo sempre centralizado ao meio na tag `<img/>` em navegador Google Chrome?

No firefox aplico apenas `display: flex` ou `inline-flex` com `align-items: center` e `justify-content: center` mas infelizmente não é uma solução crossbrowser.

```css
#Img {
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id='Img' src="" onerror="this.alt = `Can't speak Hello world!`" alt="Hello wolrd">
```

Comment: Cara na verdade acho que vc está estilizando errado sua "imagem quebrada" olha esse pergunta bem parecida que eu mesmo fiz. E veja as resposta. A que chega mais perto da sua é a resposta que está com 3 pontos no momento. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321138/como-fazer-um-estilo-para-imagem-quebrada-quando-a-imagem-n%C3%A3o-carrega se for isso mesmo que vc precisa me fala, que ai a gente vota pra fechar essa como duplicata ok. Por enquanto removi a minha resposta que estava incompleta.

Comment: @hugocsl Verifiquei a resposta lá. 
Infelizmente ela não deixa automaticamente no centro igual a solução que utilizo no firefox. Eu teria sempre que programar o `top: valor` com midia-query para ficar ao "centro" sempre que a resolução mudar.

Comment: Então fica complicado mesmo, da uma olhada tb nas outras opções lá com JS etc. as vezes algo te serve...