# src sem imagem não desaparece

Tags: javascript, json

Eu estou a usar o JSON com base de dados e eu estou com um problema: quando não há uma imagem no JSON, em vez da tag `<img>` não aparecer, ela aparece como se a imagem desse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de quando o `src` nao é encontrado no JSON, a tag `img` não aparecer?

Código:

```
var image3: obj.imagem3;
var image: obj.imagem;

$("#imagemareas3").attr("src", this.image3);
$("#imagemareas").attr("src", this.image);


<img class="imageminfo" id="imagemareas" src="">
<img class="imageminfo" id="imagemareas3" src="">
```

JSON:

```
[    
    {
        "titulo": "Exemplo",
        "imagem": "",
        "imagem3": "",
        "id": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Sim, não inserir a imagem na página ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas eu preciso disso porque em outros arrays do json ja tem la uma imagem mas para caso não tenha uma imagem aquilo desaparece

Comment: Exatamente. Não faz sentido você inserir o elemento `<img>` na página se o `src` será vazio.

Comment: Se te interessa vc sabia que vc pode estilizar e customizar uma imagem que não carrega? Elá não precisa aparece assim vc pode tratar a imagem que falha no carregamento, leia mais aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321138/como-fazer-um-estilo-para-imagem-quebrada-quando-a-imagem-n%C3%A3o-carrega

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O ideal seria a TAG `img` nem existir no `DOM` e não esconder a mesma. Como notei que faz uso do jQuery, deixo abaixo algumas opções com o framework e também uma opção com CSS (que não recomendaria, uma vez que você não quer a imagem no DOM).

## Opção 1 (recomendada)

Você poderia adicionar as imagens no DOM, apenas se o endereço não fosse vazio. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

**html**

```
<!-- div onde as imagens vão ser renderizadas -->
<div id="images"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
// código javascript para adicionar elas na div
if(obj.imagem)
   $('#images').append('<img src="'+obj.imagem+'" />');
if(obj.imagem3)
   $('#images').append('<img src="'+obj.imagem3+'" />');
```

## Opção 2

Você também pode remover a imagem do DOM caso a propriedade não seja preenchida. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
this.image3 ? $("#imagemareas3").attr("src", this.image3) : $("#imagemareas3").remove();
this.image ? $("#imagemareas").attr("src", this.image) : $("#imagemareas").remove();
```

## Opção 3

Mas caso insista em manter a `TAG` no `DOM` você pode fazer uso do `CSS` para esconder a imagem (vale lembrar que é apenas uma solução de contorno e não recomendo o uso), segue exemplo:

```
img[src=""],img[src="null"], img[src="undefined"] {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: Está correcto assim que poder eu dou-te o certo!

Comment: @DavidMv combinado, eu atualizei a resposta com uma segunda opção.

Comment: A "segunda opção" deveria ser a primeira (e única) opção. Eu recomendaria primeiro ensinar a fazer certo, depois fazer gambiarra (opcional).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você está correto, vou atualizar a resposta!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado a observação, resposta atualizada.