# Exibir uma imagem quando outra não é carregada

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-core

Olá,
Eu estou fazendo uma página web na qual as imagens são pegas de fora do servidor, porém algumas vezes a imagem não existe mais, ou o link quebrou, então, eu gostaria de exibir uma outra imagem.
O código seria assim:

```
    @if(condição de imagem existe){
    <img src="@imgUrl"/>

    }else{//aqui é quando a imagem não for encontrada, se isso ocorrer eu quero que carregue uma imagem do meu servidor

    <img src="/img.jpg"/>

    }
```

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321138/como-fazer-um-estilo-para-imagem-quebrada-quando-a-imagem-n%c3%a3o-carrega mas é só com HTML/CSS, tem resposta com JS lá tb que funciona exatamente como vc quer

Comment: eu gostaria de fazer sem javascript, já que estou usando o razor para construir a página.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o atributo `onerror` na própria tag. Esse atributo irá executar um código caso haja falha no carregamento da imagem, e esse código pode ser alterando o `src` da imagem pelo da imagem padrão que você quiser.

Vou colocar abaixo 2 exemplos, um com falha e outro sem falha:

#### Com falha

```css
img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="nada aqui ou um caminho inexistente" onerror="this.src = 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png'">
```

#### Sem falha

```css
img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" onerror="this.src = 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png'">
```