# Inserir uma imagem default caso não seja inserido uma

Tags: php, mysql, imagem

Eu quero saber se o ficheiro está vazio ou não e se não inserir uma **imagem default** na variável antes de inserir

Isto é o que eu tenho até agora, tenho também uma parte de **type** que verifica o tipo da sessão

```
 <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="inpFile" id="inpFile" class="inputfile"  />

<button type="submit" id="insert" name="insert"> Editar </button>
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
 $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["inpFile"]["tmp_name"]));
 $username = trim($_REQUEST["username"]);
//Check if image is empty
 if(empty($file)){
   if($type == 1 || $type == 2 || $type == 3 || $type == 4){
     //Set $file a predefined image 
   }
 }
 $sql = "INSERT INTO pratos (name, image) VALUES ('$username', '$file')";
 $pdo->exec($sql);

}
```

Esta foi a tentativa que fiz ao tentar inserir um **valor default**

```
$file = "../img/prato_default.png";
```

Eu quero arranjar uma forma de inserir uma **default image e mostrá-la** noutra página

```
$pesquisa = "SELECT * FROM pratos";
$resultado_pesquisa = mysqli_query($conn, $pesquisa);

<?php while ($rows_pesquisas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_pesquisa)) { ?>
<img <?php echo 'src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($rows_pesquisas['imagem']) . '"'; ?> class="image">
```

Comment: Cara não é com PHP, mas é com CSS puro, e talvez te interesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321138/como-fazer-um-estilo-para-imagem-quebrada-quando-a-imagem-n%c3%a3o-carrega

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa verificar se o arquivo foi enviado se não coloque o valor default:

```
if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
    if(isset($_FILES['inpFile'])) $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["inpFile"]["tmp_name"]));
    else $file = "../img/prato_default.png";
...
```

Comment: E depois como é que eu vou buscar à base de dados e mostro a imagem?
Quando tetei não mostrou nenhuma imagem mesmo tendo enviado o path para a base dedados

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $caminhoDaImagem ?>" />, se não mostrar, está salvando o caminho errado.