# Como ocultar o ícone da tag <img> quando a imagem não for encontrada?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Fiz um botão de **upload** que exibe uma pré-visualização da imagem selecionada, mas para isto, a tag **`img`** tem seu atributo `src` vazio. Portanto, aparece este **ícone** que está apontado com a seta.

> [image]

Já tentei de tudo, coloquei os atributos `title`, `alt` e mesmo assim continua exibindo! Então tive a ideia de utilizar [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) mas também não tive êxito!

Os atributos `alt` e `title` estavam preenchidos, então cheguei a conclusão de que não é por eles estarem vazios..

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

Já com o JavaScript, seleciono a tag `img` e verifico se o atributo `src` está "nulo", se sim, define o estilo `display` como "none", mas ainda não funcionou!

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img").src;

if (src == null) {
    img.style.display = "none";
}
```

Aqui está toda estrutura dentro do `body` da página

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="image">
         <img src="" alt="" title="">
      </div>

      <div class="content">
         <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="text">
            Nenhuma Imagem Selecionada
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cancel-btn">
         <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="file-name">
         File name here
      </div>
   </div>
   <button onclick="defaultBtnActive()" id="custom-btn">Selecione uma Imagem</button>
   <input id="default-btn" type="file" hidden>
</div>
```

Como faço para ocultar aquele ícone quando não houver nenhuma imagem?

Comment: Seu pergunta esta bem estruturada mais não coloca código fonte em formato de imagem, isso dificulta para quem vai tentar responder.  Veja como formata código de fonte em sua perguta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: sorry, irei refazer a pergunta

Comment: Utilize o atributo/evento [`onerror`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp) do [tag:html], da seguinte forma: `<img src="" alt="" title="" onerror="this.style.display = 'none'" />` que irá resolver este detalhe!

Comment: ja tentei mas quando eu seleciono a imagem ela não aparece visualmente

Comment: Ela não aparece porque quando o site é carregado, a tag `img` não tem `src` e o evento `onerror` é invocado. Quando isso acontece, o estilo `display` da tag recebe o valor `none`. Quando você altera a imagem para ela receber o arquivo que o usuário fez o upload, você aparentemente se esquece de alterar o `display: none` para `display: block` ou outro valor que a torne visível. Teste declarar a tag assim ` <img src="" alt="" onerror='this.style.display = "none"' onload='this.style.display = "block"'/>  `.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como fazer um estilo para "imagem quebrada" (quando a imagem não carrega)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321138/como-fazer-um-estilo-para-imagem-quebrada-quando-a-imagem-n%c3%a3o-carrega)

Comment: tentei, mas o erro ainda persiste :´)